# I have added dependency in Pom.xml but Maven is not picking up, maven build gets fails

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, maven

I need to use gson jar for saving a POJO file to java.For this I added its dependency in Pom.xml

[image]

I have this jar in my local m2 repository

[image]

But in import statement I am getting this error
[image]
[image]

I did update project and clean project but didn't resolved the issue.

I then added this jar through add external jar
[image]

With this the compilation error got resolved
[image]

But when I do Maven install and Maven build it gets failed, the error I am getting is:

[image]

It is giving error on import statement, for Gson.

Adding the updated pom.xml
[image]

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>configurator</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../parent-pom/pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.csc.fs.accel.browser</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.csc.fs.accel.browser.dictionary.rest</artifactId>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>

    <name>com.csc.fs.accel.browser.dictionary.rest Blueprint Bundle</name>
    <description>com.csc.fs.accel.browser.dictionary.rest OSGi blueprint bundle project.</description>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.csc.fs.accel.browser</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.csc.fs.accel.browser.dictionary.service</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jcr</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcr</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.emf.common</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.emf.ecore</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.emfjson</groupId>
            <artifactId>emfjson-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0</version>
        </dependency> -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipselabs</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipselabs.emfjson</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.csc.fs</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.csc.fs.storage.service</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.csc.fs.pa</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.csc.fs.pa.common.exception</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.csc.fs.pa</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.csc.fs.pa.common.service</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.csc.fs.accel</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.csc.fs.accel.etools.datadictionary.model</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.csc.fs.accel</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.csc.fs.accel.etools.common.usability.api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.csc.fs.accel</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.csc.fs.accel.etools.common.model</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.xsd</groupId>
                <artifactId>xsd</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.3</version>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
                <groupId>com.csc.fs.pa</groupId>
                <artifactId>
                    com.csc.fs.pa.allowedValue.service
                </artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.7</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <Bundle-Version>${project.version}</Bundle-Version>
                        <Export-Package>com.csc.fs.accel.browser.dictionary.rest*;version=${project.version}</Export-Package>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.csc.fs.accel</groupId>
                <artifactId>
                    com.csc.fs.accel.etools.datadictionary.model
                </artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.csc.fs.accel</groupId>
                <artifactId>com.csc.fs.accel.etools.common.usability.api</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.csc.fs.accel</groupId>
                <artifactId>
                    com.csc.fs.accel.etools.common.model
                </artifactId>
                <version>2.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
</dependency>       
</dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

</project>
```

Can anyone please suggest what I am missing or how should i resolve this error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got wrong dependency declared. It should be

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
</dependency>
```

while your `groupId` is     `<groupId>com.google.code.gson.gson</groupId>` - notice double `.gson` at the end.

**UPDATE:**

So as you have pasted your POM now we can see what is the problem.
You have given dependency (gson) in **Dependency Managemet** not in **Dependencies**. You have to include it in **Dependencies** as well. To understand what dependency management is, read mavens doc https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

Comment: I added the dependency as you suggested, then done update project and Maven build and install. But still it is not taking this dependency. Also in my local m2 i didn't see gson of 2.7 version. Please suggest what should i do next.

Comment: @FatemaRangwala `mvn clean install should` should work. Attach your `POM` content to the question.

Comment: @FatemaRangwala paste whole `POM` not a screenshot... basicly you should not attach screenshots like you did at all (that is why question is downvoted)

Comment: ok, i thought to add screenshot of only portions related to question. Got your point. Pasted the pom.xml.

Comment: @FatemaRangwala and as you can see, screenshots were useless in your case, `pom` content on the other hand saved the day :)

Comment: I agree, from next time onward will add the whole contents. Thank you for your help and suggestion.